# Parsing Json in JQuery get error "ReferenceError: href is not defined"

Tags: php, jquery, html, json, mongodb

When i try parse json from connection.php and using this is jquery :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("document").ready(function() {
        $.getJSON('connection.php', {
            cid: href,
            format: 'json'
        }, function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(index, element) {
                /* mengisikan table dari hasil json */
                $('#tabledata').find('tbody')
                    .append($('<tr>')
                        .append(
                            '<td>' + data.sys + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + element.procid + '</td>'
                        )
                    );
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>

</html>
```

I got *error* :

> ReferenceError: href is not defined
>   $.getJSON('connection.php', { cid:href, format:'json' },
>   function(data) {

Comment: As you can see variable `href` is not defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use quotes around `href` if you want to send `cid` value as string `href`.

```
$.getJSON('connection.php', { cid: 'href', format:'json' }, function(data) {
//                                 ^    ^
```

If `href` is variable, make sure it is in the scope of `getJSON`.

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    var href = 'www.google.com'; // Defined here

    $.getJSON('connection.php', { cid:href, format:'json' }
```